# Where is this lake/mountain scene?

Tags: where-on-earth

Where is this picture taken? It's a backdrop for a video conferencing system by Polycom. I'm aware it might be a composite image, but hopefully the main location can be identified.

[image: fewfew]

I've tried reverse image searching but haven't found a match.

Appologies for the poor quality, I couldn't find a full image so had to take a screenshot of Polycom's marketing video here: http://www.polycom.com/voice-conferencing-solutions/conference-phones/trio.html#videos. I deliberately haven't stripped out the text as I wanted to included as much of the context as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in Austria. Just search for Hallstatter-see-lake.